# Single sign on: not able to run demo app given on google site

Tags: php, openid, single-sign-on

I am not able to run demo app as given on http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html

It throws following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addExtension() on a non-object in C:\test\htdocs\index.php on line 46

I want to integrate my application using 2-Legged Oauth on a google app account.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working behind a proxy server. Fixing proxy in library solved this issue.